# Magento Layered Product Collection on CMS page

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, layered-navigation

I need code to get products collection as it filtered by layer filters. So we need to get collection and apply some filters to it.

For example I have CMS page and on it I show some block by code like {{block type=.... template=....}}. How can I show 30 products w/o toolbars but as they listed on page http:// somedomain/category?manufacturer=3&size=5 (so we have some category name and few filter values, filters and category can be different from 1 block to another)

Comment: I believe this is not posible with only CMS directives - custom PHP code would be required.

Comment: I know that it's not possible with only CMS directives - I created extention for that and call it over block, but I didn't know how to add code (PHP code) to do that. Will see extention in first answer and add to it functionality to use urls instead of attribute value. The reason to use urls - I can use more than one attribute and on this site we use Amasty Improved Navigation - so I will use seo urls for this (like they used on site in catalog, so we can copy url from site and insert it into CMS page)

Answer (score 0):

Yoast has created a module for filterings products into a CMS landing page. You can have a look at it here: http://yoast.com/landing-pages-module-magento/

The module allows you to filter on specifications and categories.

Comment: thnx - will see it as example